# Ubuntu 18.04 failed upgrade from 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I ran `do-release-upgrade -d` but
the upgrade failed with an error message saying packages have unmet dependencies.

`sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` also failed to fix the errors.

Here is the full error message:

```
Correcting dependencies... failed.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 checkbox-converged : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable
 gnome-calendar : Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.21.2) but 3.18.1-1ubuntu1 is installed

 gnome-session : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.25.91-0ubuntu4~) but it is not installed

                 Depends: gnome-session-bin (>= 3.28.1-0ubuntu2) but 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 is installed

                 Depends: gnome-session-common (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu2) but 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 is installed

                 Depends: xwayland but it is not installed

                 Recommends: fonts-cantarell but it is not installed

                 Recommends: adwaita-icon-theme-full

                 Recommends: gnome-themes-extra but it is not installed
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-17 (>= 3.17.92) but it is not installed
                         Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.20) but 3.18.1-1ubuntu1 is installed

 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.24) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed

 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed

 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed

 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.9.5) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is installed

                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-9-5

                Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5

 libunity-webapps0 : Depends: unity-webapps-service but it is not installable
 libwayland-egl1-mesa : Depends: libegl1 but it is not installed

 qml-module-qtquick-controls : Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.9.5) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is installed

                               Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                               Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                               Depends: qtbase-abi-5-9-5

                               Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5

 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs : Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.9.5) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is installed

                              Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                              Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-9-5

                              Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5

 qml-module-qtquick-window2 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                              Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5

 qml-module-qtwebkit : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed

                       Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5
 qml-module-ubuntu-test : Depends: qml-module-ubuntu-components but it is not installable

                          Depends: libubuntugestures5 but it is not installable

 qml-module-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin (>= 1.3) but it is not installable or

                                                qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles (>= 1.3) but it is not installable

 qml-module-ubuntu-web : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin (>= 1.3) but it is not installable or

                                  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles (>= 1.3) but it is not installable

 unity-control-center : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-17 (>= 3.27.90) but it is not installed

                        Recommends: system-config-printer but it is not installed

                        Recommends: gnome-control-center-faces but it is not installed

 unity-webapps-qml : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable or

                              qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles but it is not installable

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

In addition, the GUI got somewhat strange.

What has happened?

Comment: How many PPAs do you have in your system?

Comment: @N0rbet: How to get that? and for what is useful?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

Open a terminal with:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
(enter your user and password)
then

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

next step

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop gdm3
```

you will be offered options how to fix the incompatibilities, hit a few times <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> until you are suggested with some removal of old packages and installing of updated one.

then give <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to a solution that removes old incompatible packages and installs the new ones.

last

```
sudo reboot
```

The above worked for me.

Comment: Why not a straight forward  `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop gdm3`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix apt will not work it says it needs dependencies but will not install them, like this `Depends: x but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: The dependency issues are interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
update-manager -cd
```

From here, try to update. If there is an error with an option that says partial upgrade, click it. This will restore the GUI. Reboot, and run the command again. There should be no error, and you can proceed with the upgrade via the GUI.

Comment: the update manager does not launch anymore, stuck at the starting.

Comment: What does the -cd option do?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have got a number of broken packages, as per the error message `E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`. To resolve, look at the file `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`. Locate the packages that are broken and remove them with `sudo apt-get remove broken-package`. If there are dependency errors, then try to reinstall the package: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall broken-package`.

Now try fixing dependency errors:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Reboot and try upgrading again.

Comment: it does not work ! file /var/log/dist-ypgrade/apt.log does not even exist! I get the same error message

Comment: Not `/var/log/dist-ypgrade/apt.log`, `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`. Does that exist?

Comment: it's a typo. No, it doesn't exist !